# How to prevent loading bitmaps in RecyclerView more than once, when onBindViewHolder calls more than once?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerView with GridLayoutManager ,
recyclerView item consist of ImageView and custom progress over it, which is update over time, but I don't need to  load every time bitmap, only progress.that is why  i use magazineId ,and when it is empty only in that case load bitmap ,but in any case from time to time it loads bitmap,the same I don't have when using LinearLayoutManager.

```
 @Override
public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.library_item, parent, false);
    SimpleViewHolder viewHolder = new SimpleViewHolder(view);
    viewHolder.id = "NONE";
    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    final Magazine magazineItem = magazines.get(position);
    String magazineId = magazineItem.getId();

    if (!viewHolder.magazineId.equals(magazines.get(position).getId())) {
        viewHolder.layoutCoverContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, coverHeigth));
        gDisplayImage(new GlideImage(magazines.get(position).getFirstPage(), true), viewHolder.glideView);
        viewHolder.magazineId = magazines.get(position).getId();
    }
viewHolder.customProgress.setPercent(percent);
}
    public void setMagazines(List<Magazine> allMagazines) {

    if (allMagazines != null) {
        if (magazines == null) {
            magazines = new ArrayList<Magazine>();
        } else {
            magazines.clear();
        }
        if (allMagazines != null) {
            magazines.addAll(allMagazines);

        } else {
            magazines.clear();
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
 public class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    GlideViewglideView;
    String magazineId;}

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clipToPadding="false" />



    private void setUpSwipRecyclerView() {
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(libraryAdapter);
}
```

Comment: are you talkibg about you start scrolling and the image gets loaded again even thnough it was loaded once?

Comment: I have recyclerView and when I click on item ,the progress starts for that item and update the whole list  ,even without scrolling it starts blinking ,onBindViewHolder() is called I need to check correctly that only progress could be changed ,not call image loading

Comment: are you calling notifiydatasetchanged by chance?

Comment: yes - notifiydatasetchanged ()

Comment: If you mean to use notifyItemChanged(position) it continues to load multiply times for the same  item